# N Tier Project in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, n-tier-architecture

I want to start a project in sharepoint 2013 from scratch. I want to follow 3 tier design in sharepoint custom application. i have created DAL, BAL, Common and Presentation Layer and i also added strong name key file with password. then i create visual webpart code it and deploy on sharepoint but when i added this webpart in sharepoint button click event is not working. Inshort i am unable to Connect all layer. i have done it in asp.net previously where it successfully working but here in sharepoint 2013 its not working. 
Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved! Just Add all layers dll's in your sharepoint 14 hives bin directory.
simple way to open iis goto your sites right click on it click explore
goto bin folder and add all dll's of dal, bal common in this folder.